# Why the long hashes in AB testing cookies?

Tags: security, cookies, ab-testing

I was wondering if someone could explain why do websites using AB testing, have a very long hash stored inside a cookie.

In the context of a single page application, let's assume that I just want to show a different background color. I can store an "AB identifier", for example 0 or 1, inside a cookie when the user logs in, and then, in my javascript code, check for that cookie's value, and render the right color.

But why are others not using simple identifiers, and they use long hashes? I mean, this can't be a security thing right? Because, no matter how long the hash might be, it still needs to be readable by the client side (javascript), so the decoding script, which might be as simple as multiple if/else statements, is still available to everyone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Techmaestro,
These things aren’t universal and depend on the tool, but typically these keys aren’t refering to your experience or a list of experiences, but rather a session key, just like your jsessionid cookie. The a/b server uses that to look up your a/b session, which isnt necessarily your HTTP session. The key has to be large to reduce the chance of collision.